# Error while installing audioplayers: ^0.19.1

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I encountered an error while installing a Flutter Package => audioplayers: ^0.19.1

I am using Flutter 4.2.2 ;

**Error:**

> Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of
> Kotlin.  The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version
> is 1.1.15.

After trying to find solution for 3 consecutive days I am now encountering this error.

**Error 2:**

> Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running
> Gradle:  // C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre // Using
> different JDK locations  on different processes might cause Gradle to
> spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a
> terminal while using Android Studio.  // More info... // Select a JDK
> from the File System  // Do not show this warning again (a minute ago)
>
> Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.10) differs
> from the  one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.21) Inspection info:
> This inspection reports that different IDE and Gradle plugin  versions
> are used. This can cause inconsistencies between IDE and Gradle builds
> in error reporting or code behaviour.
>
> JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library
> versions  may be available elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

> Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.10) differs
> from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.5.21)

You need to use the same version of kotlin on your root android module with your Android Studio kotlin version.

So, change the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    ...
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of
> Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version
> is 1.1.1

You are using an updated version while the metadata requires an obsolete one. That's why, its not working.